How to categorize table columns by table results and return header as results

I would like to create a table that uses data from another, where the results become the column headers (static) and returns the headers from table 1.  As there will be duplicate results in table 1, it must somehow show both values associates with column A.  I apologize if I am not asking this correctly.  It is one of those things that seems like it should be simple but isn't. Thank you
I have tried multiple INDEX and MATCH functions but haven't gotten it quite right

One way in powerquery after bringing in the data with data ... from table/range .... is to paste this into home ... advanced editor...
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index2", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Column1", "Index2"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Column1", "Value"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Attribute", "Index","Index2"}, {"Attribute", "Index","Index2"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded data",{{"Value", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows", each ([Value] <> 0)),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows", {{"Value", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows", {{"Value", type text}}, "en-US")[Value]), "Value", "Attribute"),
#"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Sort(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Index2", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows1",{"Index", "Index2"})
in #"Removed Columns"



Thank you.  I can see how this works. I guess I should have mentioned that the table I am pulling from is also pulling from another power query.  I managed to get this to work by creating a helper table as a go between and it worked.  Except now, all the items in Column1 are listed 22 times each, including rows that have no data.

I also should mention that the duplication of items in column1 will never be more than four times

Number of dupes is irrelevant to how I set up the answer for you. Does it work?

I also use "Unpivot Other Columns" to flatten the data:

But after that, I decided to group by "Column1" first.

And then for each sub table, I group by "Value":

The code:
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
  flattened = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
  grouped = Table.Group(flattened, {"Column1"}, {{"All", each _, type nullable table[Column1 = any, Attribute = text, Value = any]}}),

  GroupByValue = 
    (Source as table) => let
        grouped = Table.Group(Source, {"Value"}, {{"List", each [Attribute]}}),
        sorted = Table.Sort(grouped, {{"Value", Order.Ascending}}),
        createTable = Table.FromColumns(sorted[List], List.Transform(sorted[Value], each Number.ToText(_)))
      in
        createTable,

  groupedByValue = Table.AddColumn(grouped, "Table", each GroupByValue([All])),
  headers = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(groupedByValue[Table],each Table.ColumnNames(_)))),
  combined = Table.ExpandTableColumn(groupedByValue, "Table", headers, headers),
  removedUnused = Table.RemoveColumns(combined, {"All"})
in
  removedUnused

